# Publish feed entries on Facebook

Tags: facebook, feeds

Is there any good, simple way to auto publish feed entries from my website to my Facebook profile? (I just need post title and link to the post).

This would be the best option, but looks like it does not work anymore:

- http://www.facebook.com/notes/blogging-with-beth/how-to-publish-your-blog-posts-to-facebook-automatically/245596473016

Comment: What are you using to create the feed?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles, Is this important? I create the feed using `Zend_Feed`, but this should work for any RSS feed, e.g. generated by Wordpress.

Comment: I was thinking of a couple of solutions for various CMS's so I could have been, as it turned out it wasn't.

Comment: There are several questions about this on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use a facebook app called RSS Graffiti, and use it to read the RSS feed of your blog posts.

Comment: +1 for RSS Graffiti. I used it for several month up until very recently and it did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook removed the ability to publish RSS feeds via the notes app about this time last year, it had become quite buggy, so I imagine they no longer wanted to support it.

The best way I know of is via the [NetworkedBlogs facebook app](http://www.networkedblogs.com/), video and tutorial over here at [andreavahl.com](https://andreavahl.com/facebook/how-to-import-your-blog-into-facebook-using-networked-blogs.php).

Answer (score 0):

[Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/) post any RSS to (FB|Twitter|...)